# Is there a way to programatically disallow file syncing via ActiveSync?

Tags: c#, registry, compact-framework, windows-ce, activesync

Is there a way to programmatically disallow the file syncing that happens between a handheld device and PC when the user checks Mobile Device Settings > Change content sync settings > File > Sync Settings?

The registry update in the link provided by josef looks promising; if I update that setting programmatically within the app that runs on the handheld, will that prevent file syncing, or do the connected PCs also need to have their registry setting modified?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible, I use the GuestOnly setting for my devices to have them all not to sync anything: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/02/26/disable-the-activesync-partnership-setup-dialog/

Comment: Ah yes, guest mode.  I recall we used to apply Guest Mode via a registry setting on PCs that were going to be cradled to,

Comment: Can this setting be done programatically from the handheld (update the registry on the PC)? Or can the registry on the *device* (only, without worrying about the PC's settings) be programatically set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This updates the "GuestOnly" registry value mentioned by josef and tcarvin:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services");
if (key != null)
{
    key.SetValue("GuestOnly", 00000001, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
}
```

I'm not sure this really disallows file synching, though...the jury is still out on that.

### UPDATE

It would seem that the key (NPI) registry value that needs to be touched (in a different way than I am touched) is "ExcludeExt"; e.g., if I don't want *.lnk, *.tmp, *.cdb, *.mdb, or *.sdf files synced:

```
key.SetValue("ExcludeExts", "lnk,tmp,cdb,mdb,sdf", RegistryValueKind.String);
```

This does work - *.SDF files in the "My Documents" folder on the handheld device are no longer synced to *C:\Users\clay\Documents\Documents on Clay's Device* on the PC.